# Servlet.service() throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: HashMap cannot be cast to Object

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jsf, servlet-3.0

this happens when i am submitting form of my jsf page and redirecting to another page

```
<p:outputPanel id="panelx" >

        <form method="post" action="https://someUrl/payment/response" id="xForm" name="xForm">

        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" size="50" maxlength="10" 
        value="#{somevalue}" />     

    <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="submit" style="display: none" />
</form>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

**but i could overcome this issue when i used jsp page and the same form in it below my jsp page**

```html
<body onload="document.paymentRedirect.submit()">

 <form method="post" name="paymentRedirect" id="paymentRedirect"  action="https://someUrl/payment/response">

      <input id="id" name="id" class="x25" size="40" type="hidden" 
      value="<% out.print(request.getParameter("id"));%>">
 
 </form>

</body>
```

the complete stack trace below,i could not understand what is happening . any help will be most appreciated

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreSystemEventListeners(UIComponentBase.java:1914)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1615)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:366)


Blockquote
```

Comment: Which version of Mojarra are you using? Did you try a recent one? It's trying to cast a `HashMap` to an array of Objects: `Object[]`

Comment: i am using javax faces 2.2.12, no i did not try with the latest one